# How can I find and move subfolders from a text file list?

Tags: list, powershell, text, move

A text file contains folder names one below the other without a path.
I need a Powershell script to search in a main folder (the one where the .ps1 file is located) for all subfolders that have these folder names from the list. They can be located somewhere, sometimes several folder levels deep.

These subfolders with all their contents are to be moved to another target folder. The target folder named "output" should be created in the same folder level as the source folder.

Since the subfolders of the list only occur once in the source folder, it is no problem to move all the folders found into the new target folder without folder hierarchy.

How can I realize this?

Comment: Is this a continuation of your previous question? Relying on the _name_ alone seems brittle - what if you had a file path like `subfolder1/name1/name1/file.txt`? Should the script move `subfolder1/name1` or `subfolder1/name1/name1`?

Comment: No, it should work with a new text list with other content. It's another task.
It can move subfolder1/name1 or subfolder1/name1/name1 because this case will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too wide and a bit amigous, so I'm just going to hand you some commandlets as resources for your project:

**Convert File lines into a Powershell List**

```
#Get File Content as a string
$File_Content_Raw=Get-Content -Path $File_Path
#Split the content based on new lines (`n)
$List=$File_Content -split "`n"
```

At this point you have a Powershell List object to easily work on.

**Get the contents of a folder (similar to LS or DIR)**

I purposely added "-Directory" to only show folders and "-Recurse" to list subfolders too.

```
$Folder_Content=Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder_Path -Directory -Recurse
```

**Check if a folder exists and create it if necessary**

```
If (Test-Path -Path $Folder_Path\$Target_Folder_Name){
  New-Item -Name $Target_Folder_Name -ItemType Directory -Path  $Folder_Path
}else{
  Write-Host "Folder $Target_Folder_Name already exists in this path."
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm adding a code snippet in case you wonder how to go through the list:

```
foreach ($Item in $List){
  Write-Host "In here do something with item $Item."
}
```

That will do a For cycle on each item of the list, loading the variable $Item with the current item according to the list position.

Comment: Thank you. I am a complete beginner and am trying to do something with it. However, I'm afraid that I won't be able to create a script from it any time soon.